# Can an admin undo the limitations of a chmod 700?

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

Please help me understand how Linux works in this respect.
I set up a samba fileshare on a raspberry pi and created a user account as well as a directory for a new user.
I then used chown and chmod 700 to make that other person the owner as well as give only them the rights to the file.
I used:

```
sudo chown newuser /somedirectory
sudo chmod -R 700 /somedirectory
```

(Edit: I forgot to mention the -R)

As expected, the admin account now can't access the directory. When I take a look at it via `ls -l`, it's listed as `d---------` which I don't understand. Shouldn't it be `drwx------` since the owner has full access?

Also, is there any way to gain back the rights to this folder? I suppose not, since otherwise a user could never be sure that an admin isn't digging around in their files, right? So the most plausible way would be, that for the admin account to gain back full rights, the new owner of that folder would now have to log in and use chmod to grant permissions to other users.

I can still use chown to set the owner of the directory back to the admin account, but that still doesn't allow me to change the permissions again.

What is going on here?

**Edit:**

To elaborate a little bit on this, I'm playing around with these settings because I'm setting up a NAS and I thought I'd give my wife her own folder to store things in. She asked if it was protected by a password, but I guess as long as I can revoke her privacy rights at any time, it's not really protected. It makes sense that Linux would work that way, given it's more often used in companies etc. and it could be disastrous if the admin himself didn't have complete access.

Comment: I added the commands I used to change the ownership/permissions of the files

Comment: Then mention the `-R`. I want to read this once. Not forwards and backwards and inside out.

Comment: "It makes sense that Linux would work that way, " — It can not be any other way, same OSes may pretend, but admin always can do anything. If all else fails, then we just remove the disk, and plug into another system.

Comment: Can you add what you found as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you've actually used `chmod 700` the resulting permissions should not be `d---------`. You're probably mixing up things, but without seeing exact facts anybody can only guess what went wrong.

Secondly, the Linux `root` account normally can modify all permissions, delete or modify all files, terminate processes etc. If you can't trust a person, don't give them root access, period.

The only way of storing files on a potentially insecure file storage is to encrypt and digitally sign them on a secure computer before storing them.

Comment: I'd used chmod -R 700 it seems. I have since been able to revert the permissions by using -R again when setting it to chmod -777... maybe I'll have to do a little reading on what -R actually does, I was under the impression it only meant that subdirectories are affected as well.

Comment: @screwloose232 no, `chmod -R 700` wouldn't do that. If you can't exactly remember (or find the command in the bash history) you won't know for sure.

Comment: I think I found my mistake: I used a - in front of the 700 or 777 because I thought I had to do this for the parameter, but that actually reversed the effect, like a bit-flip. So -777 effectively became 000 I suppose!

Comment: @screwloose232, no ... if you read `man chmod` you'll see that `+` adds permissions and `-` takes them away. So you took away `700` from the existing `700` and got left with `000`, i.e. `d---------`

Comment: @roaima that makes sense as well. I understand these commands a little bit better now, so thank you!